# How to attach 'enhanced image' plugin within ckedior5?

Tags: ckeditor5

here I've successfully used ckeditor in my project. But I need to use ckeditor: enhanced-image (image2) which is not provided in their built. So I need to create a custom built to achieve my target. I'm trying a lot to figure out this but I can not achieve my goal.

Please help me to create a ckeditor with 'enhanced-image' plugin. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [Enhanced Image](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2) plugin is dedicated to CKEditor 4 only and there is no way to run it in CKEditor 5 (and there won't be; v4 and v5 features are not interchangeable).

As of yet, there's no CKEditor 5 plugin that would provide the exact editing experience. You can check out some discussions about [setting image dimensions](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/issues/216) and the [image resizer](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/issues/241) feature we plan to release to learn more, though.